# How to install Kibana on Machine 1 (ES running on Machine 2) and debug

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a typical scenario. Due to some contraints, need to install Kibana on Machine 1 and Elastic Search is running on Machine 2. Then Kibana on Machine 1 needs to debug from ES on Machine 2.

Can anyone share the steps on this type of installation please.

Thanks

Comment: What did you mean by `Then Kibana on Machine 1 needs to debug from ES on Machine 2` ? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: for do that you need to bind es on the internet. Why you can't install kibana on the same machine of ES and then query that kibana from machine2? on browser http://machine1:5601 ?